# How can I obtain a Google Access Token using OAuth 2.0 in PHP or cURL, using fixed email, password, client_secret, client_id, and project_id?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I am currently using the Google file translate API to translate documents in my project. You can find more information about this API at https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents.

This API requires an OAuth 2 access token. However, I do not want to display the Google login to my users in order to use this API. Instead, I would like to utilize my own Gmail account, password, and other necessary details to obtain the access token.

I have used Google API Client Library for PHP OAuth 2.0 to get the access token. It's working fine but i have to login with my email and password everytime.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: please edit your question and include your code